# How do I use function elgg_view_input()?

Tags: php, elgg

I would like to go over the fact that
**elgg_view_input()** is DEPRECATED in **Elgg v2.3.4**

```
$footer = '';
foreach ($controls as $control) {
    $type = elgg_extract('input', $control, 'text');
    unset($control['input']);
    $footer .= elgg_view_input($type, $control);
}
```

Comment: Is this a question or some kind of note? It'd be better if you could re-phrase it with a specific problem in the question and then self-answer if you have a solution.

Comment: tadman the question mark in the title indicates the question. The footnote explains the question and the answer. The problem is that the function has been deprecated and I showed examples of how to use the new one.

Comment: All though loosely connected to php the post is about two proprietary functions, one that is deprecated and one that is not. SInce the php file in question is using a java header you might do better to add a Java tag. However, the focus is Elgg and has little or nothing to do with PHP itself.

Comment: There's good information in here but it's not in the correct format. Unlike a form or wiki, Stack Overflow has a hard separation between question and answer. If you could move the answer components to an answer section then it'd look better, plus you can accept that answer and it's flagged as "answered" when anyone searches.

Comment: Since this code is in PHP, the PHP tag applies. Elgg is just something that uses PHP, it's not indepdent of it. Java has nothing to do with it since there's zero Java code here.

Comment: No problem Thanks

Comment: Looking good now! Accept that when you can as this will mark the question as complete.

Answer (score 1):

**Use elgg_view_field() instead.**

EXAMPLE #1

```
  <?php

echo elgg_view_field(['#type' => 'text', 'name' => 'sitename', '#label' => elgg_echo('installation:sitename'), 'value' => elgg_get_config('sitename')]);
echo elgg_view_field(['#type' => 'text', 'name' => 'sitedescription', '#label' => elgg_echo('installation:sitedescription'), 'value' => elgg_get_config('sitedescription')]);
echo elgg_view_field(['#type' => 'email', 'name' => 'siteemail', '#label' => elgg_echo('installation:siteemail'), 'value' => elgg_get_site_entity()->email, 'class' => 'elgg-input-text']);
echo elgg_view_field(['#type' => 'number', 'name' => 'default_limit', '#label' => elgg_echo('installation:default_limit'), 'value' => elgg_get_config('default_limit'), 'min' => 1, 'step' => 1]);
echo elgg_view_field(['#type' => 'select', 'name' => 'language', '#label' => elgg_echo('installation:language'), 'value' => elgg_get_config('language'), 'options_values' => get_installed_translations()]);
$footer = elgg_view('input/submit', ['value' => elgg_echo('save')]);
elgg_set_form_footer($footer);
```

EXAMPLE #2

```
   <?php

/**
 * Used to show plugin settings for both users and admins.
 *
 * @package Elgg.Core
 * @subpackage Plugins
 */
$plugin = elgg_extract('entity', $vars);
$plugin_id = $plugin->getID();
$user_guid = elgg_extract('user_guid', $vars, elgg_get_logged_in_user_guid());
// Do we want to show admin settings or user settings
$type = elgg_extract('type', $vars, '');
if ($type != 'user') {
    $type = '';
}
if (elgg_view_exists("plugins/{$plugin_id}/{$type}settings")) {
    echo elgg_view("plugins/{$plugin_id}/{$type}settings", $vars);
}
echo elgg_view_field(['#type' => 'hidden', 'name' => 'plugin_id', 'value' => $plugin_id]);
echo elgg_view_field(['#type' => 'hidden', 'name' => 'user_guid', 'value' => $user_guid]);
$footer = elgg_view_field(['#type' => 'submit', 'value' => elgg_echo('save')]);
elgg_set_form_footer($footer);
```

EXAMPLE #3

```
/**
 * Widget edit num_display
 *
 * @uses $vars['entity']  ElggWidget
 * @uses $vars['name']    (optional) The name of the attribute, defaults to 'num_display'
 * @uses $vars['default'] (optional) The default value if no value is set, defaults to first option
 */
$widget = elgg_extract('entity', $vars);
if (!$widget instanceof \ElggWidget) {
    return;
}
unset($vars['widget']);
$name = elgg_extract('name', $vars, 'num_display');
$vars['name'] = "params[{$name}]";
if (!isset($vars['label'])) {
    $vars['label'] = elgg_echo('widget:numbertodisplay');
}
$vars['#label'] = $vars['label'];
unset($vars['label']);
if (!isset($vars['options'])) {
    $vars['options'] = [5, 8, 10, 12, 15, 20];
}
$value = sanitize_int($widget->{$name}, false);
if (!$value) {
    $value = elgg_extract('default', $vars, $vars['options'][0]);
}
$vars['value'] = $value;
$vars['#type'] = 'select';
echo elgg_view_field($vars);
```

I have been asked this question about 50 times. So I thought I would answer it here in hopes that if anyone else has recently upgraded Elgg this might be of some help.